# Paymill + Heroku + Rails 4 No Token Found Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paymill

I've integrated Paymill successfully in my ROR4 App using their Paymill Bridge. All works fine in development mode, but as soon as I deploy it to production, it returns me the "NO TOKEN FOUND".

This used to happen in development mode because it was not loading the transactions.js properly due to turbolinks, I have fixed it since.

But cannot make it work in production

Thanks!
All the Best

Comment: Are all (JS) libs properly available in prod mode, do you receive a token from the bridge? Do you use the test or live public key to request the token?

Comment: All Js are properly available live yes. And I use the the test public key

Comment: And do you receive a token from the bridge with your live public key?

Answer (score 1):

since the introduction of the assets pipeline, rails uses **gem uglier** to compress (remove whitespaces, shorten function and variable names, etc.) the custom JavaScript. This is done by the command **rake assets:precompile**, which is executed on each deploy to heroku.

I think you should take a look at [uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) and try to overwrite the default settings. My first guess is that you have to set **:unused** to **false**. Because the PAYMILL_PUBLIC_KEY variable is used by [PAYMILL bridge](https://bridge.paymill.com) and not by your scripts.

You can test this on your local machine by calling: **rake assets:precompile** and check the generated JavaScript.